# Parameters defined in OpenAPI for AWS API Gateway are not created

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I am working on creating an API Gateway interface for my Lambda.
I have the YAML section below. The path `cse` is properly created, but the parameters are not. Any ideas?

```
CSEApiGateway:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      Name: CSEApiGateway
      StageName: Prod
      Cors: "'*'"
      DefinitionBody:
        openapi: "3.0.1"
        info:
          description: 'API for Google CSE Lambda'
          version: '1.0.0'
          title: API for Google CSE Lambda
        paths:
          /cse:
            get:
              parameters:
                qParam:
                  name: q
                  in: query
                  description: 'The query for CSE'
                  required: false
                  schema:
                    type: string
              responses:
                '200':
                  description: "OK"
                  headers:
                    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
                      type: string
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                uri:
                  Fn::Sub: 'arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${CSELambda.Arn}/invocations'
                responses:
                  default:
                    statusCode: 200
                    responseTemplates:
                      - text/html: "$input.path('$')"
                    responseParameters:
                      method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "'*'"
                requestParameters:
                  - integration.request.querystring.q: "method.request.querystring.q"
```

See the image of the created API in the console - the parameter is missing from both the "Method Request" section and the "Integration Request" section.

API Gateway Screenshot

[image: API Gateway Screenshot]

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a yaml expert, but it looks like you're specifying parameters as a map instead of  a list.

Check out the example here:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/examples/v3.0/petstore.yaml#L17

I think your yaml should look more like:

```
parameters:
   - name: q
     in: query
     description: 'The query for CSE'
     required: false
     schema:
       type: string
```